# Filtering using elequent in laravel, show all data to start

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

So basically i have a datatable with approx 20000 rows of data, i have a few different filters and am trying to work out the best way to apply the filters. I have basically applied them to the elequent query, except the where like statement will originally be "" which is fine for any of the rows which have data, except some of the rows have NULL which is not included in the like "" statement. Is there a better way i should be doing this? Or am i just going to have to write a few if staments to check whether the filter needs to be applied yet

```
        // Fetch records
    $records = IndirectAggregate::orderBy($columnName,$columnSortOrder)
        ->where('wholesaler', 'like', '%' . $search_wholesaler . '%')
        ->where('state', 'like', '%' . $search_state . '%')
        ->where('banner_name', 'like', '%' . $search_banner . '%')
        ->select('*')
        ->skip($start)
        ->take($rowperpage)
        ->get();
```

Comment: you mean if `$search_wholesaler` have values, then you have to apply the filter, otherwise not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$records = IndirectAggregate::orderBy($columnName,$columnSortOrder)
->where(function($q) use($search_wholesaler){
  $q->where('wholesaler', 'like', '%' . $search_wholesaler . '%')
  ->orWhereNull('wholesaler');
})
->where(function($q) use($search_state){
  $q->where('state', 'like', '%' . $search_state . '%')
  ->orWhereNull('state');
})
->where(function($q) use($search_banner){
  $q->where('banner_name', 'like', '%' . $search_banner . '%')
  ->orWhereNull('banner_name');
})
->select('*')
->skip($start)
->take($rowperpage)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to use orWhere when using **like**.

```
 $records = IndirectAggregate::orderBy($columnName,$columnSortOrder)
        ->where('wholesaler', 'like', '%' . $search_wholesaler . '%')
        ->orWhere('state', 'like', '%' . $search_state . '%')
        ->orWhere('banner_name', 'like', '%' . $search_banner . '%')
        ->select('*')
        ->skip($start)
        ->take($rowperpage)
        ->get();
```